# Homology of spherical braid groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, group-cohomology, geometric-group-theory, braid-groups

By the spherical braid group, I mean the fundamental group of the configuration space of distinct unordered points in $S^2$. I am wondering what is known about the group homology of the spherical braid group. From its presentation, one can calculate $H_1$. Have the higher homology groups been compute? Is there a geometric way of thinking about the classifying space of the spherical braid group (for example is it the configuration space of points in $S^2$ with some extra data to kill off the higher homotopy groups of $S^2$)?

Comment: Let $PConf$ denote ordered configuration spaces, and $Conf$ unordered configuration spaces, so $Conf_n = PConf_n/S_n$.  There is a fibration $PConf_n(S^2)/S_{n-1} \to S^2$ which forgets everything but the last point.  The fibre over $\infty$ is $Conf_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.  From that you can analyze the homology of $PConf_n(S^2)/S_{n-1}$.  This is then a degree $n$ cover of what you want, $Conf_n(S^2)$.